# In C, how do read a list of integers from a text stream and turn them into an array?

Tags: c

The specific assignment presents me with a file "data.txt" that contains several lists of integers, such as:

```
12 9 8 7 6 4 4 7 19 1 2 8 17
20 1 2 3 4 9 7 6 5 1 10 88 2 67 81 9 2 7 6 1 10
etc.
```

The first number in each line is the number of integers in the subsequent array. I am to sort each line. So for example, the first line indicates that there are 12 integers in the following array {9, 8, 7, etc.}. My idea is to isolate each individual line, read the first integer of that line (e.g. 12) and use that to instantiate an array of that size, then read the subsequent integers into the array using a for loop. If that can be accomplished, then I have already written the rest of the code to accept that array and sort it.

I am able to use the `getline()` function to access the "data.txt" file and get each individual line of the text. But I do not know how to then scan that line of text to isolate the individual integers. I have tried `scanf()` but that is obviously not right. And I have tried `fscanf()`, which works if I delete all the lines except the first one from the data.txt file, but not otherwise.

I have put several entire work days into this homework assignment and am now at the point where I am screaming at my monitor. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fscanf(fp,"%d",&num);` to read each of the integer from the file into an `int` called `num`.
For example in case of this problem, you can read the first integer from the file (`n`), now you can use `fscanf()` `n` times storing each of the integer you get into an `int` array until you reach the next line where there is another integer `n`, read it and use `fscanf()` again for `n` times storing the integers you get into an `int` array. Repeat this process until you reach the end of the file.